# Github action - ##[error]File not found: 'tar'

Tags: github, github-actions

whenever I run using `runs-on: self-hosted` it always return an below error but there is no error if I run using `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`.

```
on:
  push:
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          echo hi
```

[image]

This machine is using `CentOS Linux 7 (Core) - Architecture: x86-64` and for this job, I have created new user called `github`. Is this because this user cannot access this `/usr/bin/tar` when running from workflow file?

Comment: Have you checked if `/usr/bin` is in the path variable?

Comment: I login as github and when I echo $PATH it return this `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/github/.local/bin:/home/github/bin`

Comment: And what happens if you run tar manually? Does it work?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly fine, I spin another VM but using Ubuntu and the error disappear.

Comment: I had this error because I had manually set the PATH variable in the .env of the actions-runner. Once I removed that, everything worked as expected again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error message. The problem seemed that the action runner directory had a empty .path file. So, I guess it used this to set the path, which effectively removed all path. My solution was to remove the empty .path file